# izip_longest on a list of lists

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

Is there a way to apply `izip_longest()` to lists inside a list?

If I have

```
somelist = [[1, 2, 3], "abcd", (4, 5, 6)]
```

is there a way to do

```
izip_longest(somelist[0], somelist[1], ....)
```

Comment: Use argument unpacking: `izip_longest(*list)`

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, it masks the built-in type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unpack the list, with the `*`, like this

```
my_list = [[1, 2, 3], "abcd", (4, 5, 6)]
izip_longest(*my_list)
```

For example,

```
from itertools import izip_longest

my_list = [[1, 2, 3], "abcd", (4, 5, 6)]
print list(izip_longest(*my_list))
```

**Output**

```
[(1, 'a', 4), (2, 'b', 5), (3, 'c', 6), (None, 'd', None)]
```

**Note:** Using `list` as a variable name will shadow the builtin [`list`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) function

If you choose to use a custom replacement value instead of `None`, you can do it like this

```
print list(izip_longest(*my_list, fillvalue = -1))
```

**Output**

```
[(1, 'a', 4), (2, 'b', 5), (3, 'c', 6), (-1, 'd', -1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `*args` calling syntax:

```
some_list = [[1, 2, 3], "abcd", (4, 5, 6)]
izip_longest(*somelist)
```

This syntax applies all elements of `somelist` as separate arguments to the called object.

This applies to all calls, not just `izip_longest()`.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> some_list = [[1, 2, 3], "abcd", (4, 5, 6)]
>>> list(izip_longest(*some_list))
[(1, 'a', 4), (2, 'b', 5), (3, 'c', 6), (None, 'd', None)]
```